# Verify Error occurring after enabling multidex in devices with android api level less than 21

Tags: android, react-native, android-multidex, verifyerror

I am facing a strange scenario where java.lang.VerifyError occurs after enabling multidex. This is happening with any library whose methods are split between the dexes. Any clue why this is happening. Been struck here for long.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I am facing a similar issue.